# Detect pan Responder Touch Coordinates

Tags: react-native

I'm using the Pan Responder to detect a touch event.

I'm doing that with:

```
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (e, gestureState) => {
        console.log(gestureState)
        console.log(e)
      },
```

However I'm not able to know where the user has touched because gestureState.x0 returns always 0. Same for gestureState.Y0

Anyone knows how can I detect that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `onPanResponderStart` event for getting gestureState.
Try this:

```
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
  onStartShouldSetPanResponder:(evt, gestureState) => true,
  onPanResponderStart: (evt, gestureState) => {
    console.log(evt, gestureState)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. `onStartShouldSetPanResponder` is the method to ask the view if it wants to become a responder at the start of a touch.

There are four methods in the PanResponder to negotiate who should be the responder.

```js
onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {...},
onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {...},
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {...},
onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => {...},
```

[Libraries/Interaction/PanResponder.js#L423](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/586d55d54f21e0fe6a0a0230a1b407693ba7d193/Libraries/Interaction/PanResponder.js#L423) For `onStartShouldSetPanResponder`, it will be called in the `onStartShouldSetResponder` function. So, we can read the [doc about ShouldSet Handlers](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/gesture-responder-system#capture-shouldset-handlers) to know these four methods briefly.

> 2. nativeEvent

If this view become the responser of that touch, you should implement any of the following methods to get the nativeEvent.

```
// The View is now responding for touch events. 
onPanResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {}, 
onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {}, 
// The end of the touch
onPanResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {}
```

- `nativeEvent`

  - `locationX` - The X position of the touch, relative to the element
  - `locationY` - The Y position of the touch, relative to the element
  - `pageX` - The X position of the touch, relative to the root element
  - `pageY` - The Y position of the touch, relative to the root element

You can use `page*` or `location*` to get the touch point relative to the particular view.

The code might be like this:

```
  this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
         console.log(e.locationX, e.locationY, e.pageX, e.pageY);
      },
  })

  <View
        {...this._panResponder.panHandlers}
      >
  </View>
```